# Html DropDownListFor isn't correctly setting the selected value; default value shown even though I'm passing in a selected value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, html.dropdownlistfor, selected

I have a search box on my page that needs to be populated with the previous search terms; i.e. if a person searches for `First name: John` the firstname box shows up with `John` already entered in.

I have several dropdown lists, and all of them work except for the `family member` dropdowns. For example, this works:

```
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Database, new SelectList(@Model.DatabaseDropdown))
```

I get a dropdown with my list of all available databases (which is in the viewmodel), and if a database was included in the search, that database is already selected. However, I have 3 more dropdowns (one for each family member search field), for selecting family members type (`Father`, `Mother`, or `Spouse`, or a default label of `Family Member`).

```
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.FamilyMembers[0].Relationship, new SelectList(@Model.FamilyTypes))
```

It's the exact same format, and I know that FamilyMembers[0].Relationship has a value, because when I add this:

```
    <text>@Model.FamilyMembers[0].Relationship</text>
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.FamilyMembers[0].Relationship, new SelectList(@Model.FamilyTypes))
```

and select `Father` from the dropdown and do a search, the page will say `Father` above the select box, but the select box itself will have the default value of `Family Members.`

**I also tried this:**

```
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.FamilyMembers[0].Relationship, new SelectList(new List<string>() { "Family Member", "Father", "Mother", "Spouse" }))
```

where I put in the select list manually, but with both versions the select list always shows up with no value selected (that is, showing `Family Members`), even though FamilyMembers[0].Relationship is a valid value in the list.

**EDIT: here's the model**

```
public class SearchResultsViewModel
{
    public List<String> CategoryDropdown { get; set; }
    public List<NehgsRelationship> FamilyMembers { get; set; } 
}

public class NehgsRelationship
{
    public String Relationship { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the `Model`?

Comment: added the model in an edit

Answer (score 0):

Try the following -

Modify your model to

```
public class SearchResultsViewModel
{
  public List<String> CategoryDropdown { get; set; }
  public List<NehgsRelationship> FamilyMembers { get; set; } 
  public String Relationship {
    get {
      return FamilyMembers[0].Relationship
    }
  }
}
```

Then Modify your View with

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Relationship, new SelectList(@Model.FamilyTypes))
```